# \includepdf let me with a blank page

Tags: pdfpages

I have some troubles with `\includepdf` because when I compile the file, the result is one blank page, but not the pdf. I have tried many things, but know I don't know. 
this is what I wrote : `\includepdf[pages=1 ; scale = 1 ; delta=0]{X.pdf}`
thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Please add it to your question ...

Comment: It's normally commas between the options, not semicolons.  With no options at all, `\includepdf{X.pdf}` should include the first page.  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: no error message, but I have the same result with only \includepdf{X.pdf}, only a blank page

Comment: using a reader to open x.pdf what size does it say those pages are

Comment: try \includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.5,delta=0 0]{x.pdf}  CUT AND PASTE EXACTLY AS I HAVE WRITTEN HERE to see if it will include at half scale then try with scale=1 for comparison main difference is use of commas and delta=0 0

Comment: I have tried tour recommandations, but it doesn't change. There is 10 pages in the pdf. And I still only have one blank page.